# Как сделать хедер на всю длину? (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хотел бы исправить хедер по краям (на скриншоте не сильно видно, но с телефона очень заметно.

```html
<header>
            <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark scrolling-navbar" style="background-color: #202025; height: 80px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;">
              <a href="#"><img class="botAvatar" src="ссылка" class="navbar-brand"></a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="background-color: #202025;">
                <div class="header">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item active" style="font-size: 20px; margin: 6px"><a class="nav-link" href="">Главная</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item" style="font-size: 20px; margin: 6px"><a class="nav-link" href="">Пригласить бота</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item" style="font-size: 20px; margin: 6px"><a class="nav-link" href="">Статус</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item" style="font-size: 20px; margin: 6px"><a class="nav-link" href="">Донат</a></li>
                  <li class="partnerButton nav-item" style="font-size: 20px; margin: 6px;"><a class="nav-link" href="">Партнеры</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
            </header>
```

css файл для телефонов:

```css
      .header {
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
      .nav-item {
        text-align: center
      }
```

Comment: Чтобы найти проблему, дайте рабочий прототип с этой проблемой. У вас есть сторонние классы в коде, которые не относятся к BS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark scrolling-navbar" style="background-color: #202025; height: 80px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;">`

Уберите: `height: 80px;`
Оно уменьшится, но когда меню выпадет оно будет на весь экран!